# How can I use geom_vline with string x-xis

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code is like this:

```
dt5 <- data.frame(x=c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), y=c(1,2,3,4))
p <- ggplot(dt5)    
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, group=x))
```

All the above code workes OK. But I want to add vline in the "bb" and "cc". So use the following code:

```
v <- c("bb", "cc")
p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept=c)
```

Since I don't have enough right to put up the image. But any one who run the code can see the vline is not shown as we thought.

I tried use as.numeric just as when x-axis is Date, but it failed. Also I tried use v <- c(2, 3), but it also failed.

So how can use geom_vline when the x-axis is string?

Comment: If I do `p + geom_vline(xintercept=2:3)`, then I get this graph: http://i.imgur.com/lKWwddn.png This is *not* what you want?

Comment: `geom_vline` needs `library(scales)`. Make sure you load that. Then follow @musically_ut 's comment and it'll work.

Comment: @LyzandeR ggplot2 imports scales.

Comment: @Roland Yeah was checking out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343530/trouble-adding-geom-vline-to-ggplot2) when posting the comment. But you are right since I reloaded R and it ran without needing to explicitly load `scales`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `geom_vline` could be improved. You can't pass it characters.

```
v <- factor(c("bb", "cc"), 
            levels=c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))

p + geom_vline(xintercept = as.integer(v))
```

Comment: @kanpu Make please consider marking the answer as accepted then, because this will probably help other users with the same problem too. Accepting an answer is not compulsory but it is encouraged when an answer has solved your problem. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)